# Question on the harmony in Sweet Child o'mine

Tags: theory, harmony, musical-forms

Sweet child o'mine has this progression in the intro:
Db (sus4)-Db-Db(sus4)-Db-Ebm11/Cb-Gb (add2)-Db (sus4)-Db-Db(sus4)-Db

And this progression in the verse:
Db-Cb-Gb-Db

How would you explain this progression (I-VIIb-IV)?
The intro and verse has this same progression but differ in one place. The intro has Ebm11/Cb. How would you explain this chord?
Should this progression be explained with classical music theory or with more modern music theory?
I remember a teacher saying that classical music is sometimes based on moving chords in thirds or sonething similar rather than being based on I-IV-V-I. Does this apply to this song/tune?

Answer (score 3):

No, this is not classical. I see it as a mixture of the folky (minor / Dorian) ⅰ - Ⅶ alternation and several blues idioms. Either you interpret it as Ⅰ - _ - Ⅳ - Ⅰ with the folk-Ⅶ in the gap borrowed from the parallel minor key (borrowing from the parallel minor is always an option in bluesy music), or you start right with the blues progression Ⅴ - Ⅳ - Ⅰ and look at it from the dominant key (Mixolydian mode).

As for the ⅱ¹¹/6, I'd not interpret too much into that. It's just the result of playing the chord progression underneath that lead guitar ostinato, which technically speaking doesn't fit over the Ⅶ♭ chord, but hey, are we lawyers, doing maths, or just playing Rock'n'Roll?

(FWIW, *that* attitude is actually not foreign in classical music, where at least pedal points are sometimes kept even when the environment has modulated to a completely foreign key.)

Answer (score 1):

You could explain it as 'cycle of 4ths'.   Make your way home through a string of plagal cadences -  a series of 'secondary subdominants' rather than the more usual secondary dominants.

It's not uncommon.  Think of the riff in the Beatles tune 'Get Back'.

Comment: Other Beatles examples include With A Little Help From My Friends, the end of Hey Jude and You've Got To Hide You're Love Away.